# Calculating whether a difference is significant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have around 30 datasets, to which I apply two models separately. I then have $e_1$ and $e_2$ which are the prediction errors on a dataset for models 1 and 2 respectively. So for each dataset, I calculate $E=e_1 - e_2$ to see which model is better at predicting that dataset. If $E>0$, then model 2 has done better, and if $E<0$ then model 1 has done better.

I then end up with 30 values of $E$, but I want to perform a statistical test that calculates which $E$ are deemed as 'statistically significant'. So I essentially want to pick out those datasets where the difference in prediction is significant.

I don't know the underlying distribution, so I'm unsure which test to apply.

Comment: Can you say more about your goals? This first sounds like a classic case of paired testing (whether t-test or Wilcoxon test or something else), but then it starts screaming "XY problem" where you have some problem X that you intend to solve with solution Y, so you ask for clarification about Y instead of X. Do you have an X you want to solve?

Comment: @Dave I want to pick out the datasets where model 2 performed significantly better than model 1. It's part of understanding for which types of datasets the model does better. I could simply pick the cases where $E>0$, but I wanted a way of quantifying whether it is statistically significant.

Comment: Do you want to make thirty comparisons (e.g., "model 1 performed better on data sets 2 and 6; model 2 performed better on the others")?

Comment: @Dave Not quite. I want to be able to say Model 2 performed significantly better on datasets 2 and 6, according to some statistical test. So it may be the case that the test picks out all the datasets or none. I don't particularly care about when Model 1 performs better. I guess the problem reduces to finding the (positive) values of $E$ which are deemed significant according to some distribution.

Comment: To me, that sounds the same as doing thirty tests. What do you see that is different?

Comment: @Dave Sorry I misunderstood you the first time - you are correct, it would be 30 tests.